# Inheritance - Creating a class Commission Employee from class Employee and testing

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, tostring, superclass

Good Morning, I've been given the assignment to:
 rewrite the CommissionEmployee class as a subclass of Employee. CommissionEmployee should contain only the instance variables and methods that are not declared in superclass Employee. CommissionEmployee's constructor should invoke Employee's constructor and CommissionEmployee's toString method should invoke Employee's toString method.
Create a Driver class to test your new CommissionEmployee class. Prompt the user to input the first name, last name, social security number, gross sales, and commission rate and create a CommissionEmployee object, using the toString method to print its information.
The issue I seem to be having is class CommissionEmployeeTest will not output what I've placed in my toString method of class CommissionEmployee. I feel like like my superclass Employee is correct as well as me test class but my belief is the error lies somewhere in the method I've created to determine the earnings. The output I'm looking for is
Employees First Name Last Name
Social Security NUmber
Earnings
Earnings would be the total of gross sales + (commission rate * gross sales)
Here is what I have along with the error:

```
class Employee
public class Employee extends Object {

    protected final String firstName;
    protected final String lastName;
    protected final String socialSecurityNumber;

    public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, String socialSecurityNumber) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.socialSecurityNumber = socialSecurityNumber;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getSocialSecurityNumber() {
        return socialSecurityNumber;
    }

    @Override

    public String toString() {
        return String.format(firstName, lastName, socialSecurityNumber);
    }
}
```

```
class CommissionEmployee
public class CommissionEmployee extends Employee {

    private double grossSales;
    private double commissionRate;
    private double earnings;

    public CommissionEmployee(String firstName, String lastName, String socialSecurityNumber, double grossSales,
            double commissionRate, double earnings) {
        super(firstName, lastName, socialSecurityNumber);       

        if (grossSales < 0.0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Gross sales must be >= 0.0");

        if (commissionRate <= 0.0 || commissionRate >= 1.0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Commission rate must be > 0.0 and < 1.0");

        this.grossSales = grossSales;
        this.commissionRate = commissionRate;
    }

    public void setGrossSales(double grossSales) {

        if (grossSales < 0.0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Gross sales must be >= 0.0");
        this.grossSales = grossSales;
    }

    public double getGrossSales() {
        return grossSales;
    }

    public void setCommissionRate(double commissionRate) {

        if (commissionRate <= 0.0 || commissionRate >= 1.0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Commission rate must be > 0.0 and < 1.0");
        this.commissionRate = commissionRate;
    }

    public double getCommissionRate() {
        return commissionRate;
    }


    public Double earnings(double d) {
        return earnings(grossSales+ (commissionRate * grossSales));
    }

    public double getEarnings() {
        return earnings;
    }

    public void setEarnings(double earnings) {
        this.earnings = earnings;
    }
    @Override

    public String toString() {

        return String.format("%s: %s %s%n%s: %s%n%s: %.2f%n%s: %.2f%n%s: %.2f%n%s",
                "commission employee", firstName, lastName,
                "social security number", socialSecurityNumber,
                "Total earnings", earnings(earnings));
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    }

    public void setSocialSecurityNumber(String socialSecurityNumber) {
    }

    public void setGrossSales(String grossSales) {  
    }

    public void setCommissionRate(String commissionRate) {
    }
}
```

```
class CommissionEmployeeTest
  //CommissionEmployee test program.
 import java.util.Scanner;

  public class CommissionEmployeeTest {
     public static void main(String[] args) { // instantiate CommissionEmployee object

        CommissionEmployee employee =  
           new CommissionEmployee(null, null, null, 0, .1, 0);

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

       // get commission employee data
       System.out.printf(
          "Employee information obtained by get methods:%n");

       System.out.printf("Enter employee's First name:");
               String firstName = input.nextLine();
               employee.setFirstName(firstName);

       System.out.printf("Enter employee's last name:");
               String lastName = input.nextLine();
               employee.setLastName(lastName);

       System.out.printf("Enter employee's social security number:");
               String socialSecurityNumber = input.nextLine();
               employee.setSocialSecurityNumber(socialSecurityNumber);

       System.out.printf("Gross sales for employee:");
               String grossSales = input.nextLine();
               employee.setGrossSales(grossSales);

       System.out.printf("Commission rate for employee:");
               String commissionRate = input.nextLine();
               employee.setCommissionRate(commissionRate);         

        System.out.printf("%n%s:%n%n%s%n",
            "Updated employee information obtained by toString",                          

          employee.toString());
    }
  }
```

Error
Employee information obtained by get methods:
Enter employee's First name:John
Enter employee's last name:Doe
Enter employee's social security number:123456789
Gross sales for employee:4000.00
Commission rate for employee:.1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at CommissionEmployee.earnings(CommissionEmployee.java:45)

I've tried manipulating my toString method in CommissionEmployee as well as my method to determine earnings but I feel like I'm spinning my wheels.  I appreciate any help.  I have 1 week left in class and feel like I can contribute more information each week when I post a question then I did the last.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue. After reviewing and revising(several times) I have found my answer.   I needed revision on my toString method as well as my earnings method.  Cleaned up quite a bit of the code and resolved.

Comment: Don't have a method named the same as an instance variable.